# android aosp project standalone build command

Tags: android

I have synced aosp project and build successfully. I add a new apk project with Android.bp makefile, it can be build with `mm` command but everytime I changed something, then re-run the `mm` command, it cost too much time.

From the console, the `mm` command will try to scan all Android.bp/Android.mk then start build current project. That's not what I want, I want a command to build current project only then build more faster.

Any suggestion I can I do that in aosp code?

Answer (score 0):

Building AOSP (with Soong build system at the moment) works exactly as you described. Even when you want to build a single project, it needs to analyze all the `Android.bp` files in the whole source tree first, then it also eventually builds dependencies you use (if anything changes there after initial build of the whole system with `m`). And AFAIK there's nothing one can do with that on the build system level.

So the first question you need to ask yourself is if you really need to build your `apk` with the system/Soong build

- if you can build your project in plain Android Studio using gradle - do that and just import apk with `Android.bp`. I see many benefits in this approach.
- otherwise, depending on your use case/constraints, I'd look for some solution to move as much as possible into regular Android development in Android Studio and then do some integration with the system. How? It depends on the constraints you have.

I'm actually in the same boat now, after developing `apk`s for years, I'm developing now applications that will be delivered with the system image, thus they can use some system or hidden apis to do some fancy things but on the other hand the development process is far from what I get used to. "With great power comes great responsibility", so I feel responsible now to improve the process.